# Windows equivalent of the 'tail' command

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there a way to simulate the *nix [tail](http://www.linfo.org/tail.html) command on the Windows command line? I have a file and I want a way to snip off the first *n* lines of text. For example:

```
D:\>type file.txt
line one
line two
line three
D:\>*[call to tail]* > result.txt

D:\>type result.txt
line two
line three
```

Comment: Doesn't `head` show only the first *n* lines instead of leaving them out?

Comment: Please Chris consider the new answers since 2009, more specifically the [Amit Portnoy's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14341672/938111). As your question is general, many user may find this web page. And they may stop reading the answers after the first one: the answer you have accepted. You can change the answer you have accepted to another more updated to nowadays possibilities. Cheers ;)

Comment: I'm a tad confused. The original question was about the Unix style `head` command, but the desired output looked like it was wanting `tail`. It looks like the answers are about `head` and not `tail`.

Comment: @blakeoft the original question was asking for the behaviour of `tail`, however the title said `head`

Comment: It is not clear in the example if the intended command is `*[call to tail]* 2 > result.txt`, in which case it is equivalent to `tail`, or `*[call to tail]* 1 > result.txt`, in which case it is not.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

No exact equivalent. However there exist a native DOS command "more" that has a +n option that will start outputting the file after the nth line:

DOS Prompt:

```
C:\>more +2 myfile.txt
```

The above command will output everything after the first 2 lines.
This is actually the inverse of Unix *head*:

Unix console:

```
root@server:~$ head -2 myfile.txt
```

The above command will print only the first 2 lines of the file.

Comment: No, it's not the same. `tail` starts counting from the end of file. So, `tail -2` will print the last two lines.

Comment: Can I print first n characters too?

Comment: @ADTC (my version of) tail doesnt support negatives. only head does  (gnuwin32)

Comment: @nl-x `-2` is not a negative. It's just a shorthand version of `-n 2` (number of lines). Unfortunately, far too many implementations of `tail` do not support `-2`, making it very inconsistent with accompanying `head` implementations which do. It has annoyed me one too many times.

Comment: @ADTC Ah sorry. I was confused with `head -n -2` which is different from `head -n 2`. But with tail, the latter doesn't exist.

Comment: Be careful if using this with redirection as implied in the question. Redirected output pauses after 65535 lines.

Comment: @ADTC most versions of `tail` also support a "how many lines from the top" behavior by prefixing the number with `+`. So regarding the example above, to get everything after the second line (e.g. the third line and below), use `tail -n +3`

Answer (score 139):

**IF** you have [Windows PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) installed (I think it's included since XP) you can just run from cmd.exe:

Head Command:

```
powershell -command "& {Get-Content *filename* -TotalCount *n*}"
```

Tail Command:

```
powershell -command "& {Get-Content *filename* | Select-Object -last *n*}"
```

or, directly from PowerShell:

```
Get-Content *filename* -TotalCount *n*
Get-Content *filename* | Select-Object -last *n*
```

**update**

PowerShell 3.0 (Windows 8 and higher) added `Tail` command with alias `Last`.
`Head` and `First` aliases to `TotalCount` were also added.

So, commands can be re-written as

```
Get-Content *filename* -Head *n*
Get-Content *filename* -Tail *n*
```

Comment: Doesn't this behave like `head` instead of `tail`?

Comment: @blakeoft yes it did... I've updated my answer. It's amazing that it took 2 year and 17 votes up before someone commented on this.

Comment: @blakeoft just realized that the question was edited! (see stackoverflow.com/posts/1295068/revisions). It originally asked for the head command... updated to include both answers...

Comment: @AmitPortnoy I found another answer somewhere on this stack exchange saying that `Get-Content` has a tail command now. For example, `Get-content -Tail 5 file.txt` will print the last five lines of file.txt. Thanks for updating your answer btw.

Comment: any way to use it as a filter? (eg. reading stdin instead of file)

Comment: actually it's included since Vista

Comment: PowerShell cannot be run in any DOS system I know.

Answer (score 27):

Powershell:

```
Get-Content C:\logs\result.txt -Tail 10

Get-Content C:\logs\result.txt -wait (monitor the tail)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, up to date and relevant (unlike cmd).
Thanks.

Comment: You can also combine them: 
Get-Content c:\Logs\Results.txt -Tail 10 -wait
This will show the last 10 lines and wait for new entries.

Answer (score 24):

```
more /e filename.txt P n
```

where n = the number of rows to display. Works fast and is exactly like `head` command.

Comment: Commands such as P, S, etc. can only be input by the user at the prompt. They cannot be passed-in to the more command. Thus, the example above does not work

Answer (score 18):

You could get [CoreUtils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) from [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/), which is a collection of standard unix tools, ported to Windows.

It, among other things, contains head.

Answer (score 13):

This is a total hack but if it's a huge file that you want to just examine the format, header, etc. and you're looking for a solution you can always just redirect the 'more' output to a new file and CTRL-C quickly. The output rows can't be controlled precisely and you will most likely kill it in the middle of a line of output but it's a cheap way of grabbing a small bit of an otherwise unusable file.

**Ex.**

```
C:\more test.csv > test.txt 
^C

C:\more test.txt 
line 1
line 2
etc......

C:\
```

Answer (score 9):

Well, this will *do* it, but it's about as fast as it looks (roughly O(n*m), where n is the number of lines to display and m is the total number of lines in the file):

```
for /l %l in (1,1,10) do @for /f "tokens=1,2* delims=:" %a in ('findstr /n /r "^" filename ^| findstr /r "^%l:"') do @echo %b
```

Where "10" is the number of lines you want to print, and "filename" is the name of the file.

Comment: +1 for a solution that took you longer to type than downloading a port of `head`.

Comment: Note: Put this expression in brackets - `(expr) > out.txt` - when sending the results to a file, or you'll only get the last line. Or append - `expr >> out.txt`.

Answer (score 8):

When using more +n that Matt already mentioned, to avoid pauses in long files, try this:

more +1 myfile.txt > con

When you redirect the output from more, it doesn't pause - and here you redirect to the console.  You can similarly redirect to some other file like this w/o the pauses of more if that's your desired end result.  Use > to redirect to file and overwrite it if it already exists, or >> to append to an existing file. (Can use either to redirect to con.)

Answer (score 6):

you can also use [Git bash](https://msysgit.github.io/) where head and tail are emulated as well

Comment: Also the official Bash on Windows https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 5):

`Get-content -Tail n file.txt` with powershell is the only thing that comes close to `tail` in linux.

The `Get-Content *filename* | Select-Object -last *n*` suggested above loads/parse the whole thing. Needless to say, it was not happy with my 10GB log file... The `-Tail` option does start by the end of the file.

Comment: I'm not sure if it does start by the end but -Tail took several minutes for a `-Tail 100` until I cancelled it. The file was slightly below 800MB

Answer (score 4):

in PS try to use command:

```
Select -Last 1
```

This command can be pipelined also.

Example to get first line:

```
type .\out.txt | Select -Last 1
```

or to get the first line:

```
 type .\out.txt | Select -First 1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the head command, one easy way to get it is to install Cygwin. Then you'll have all the UNIX tools at your disposal.

If that isn't a good solution, then you can try using findstr and do a search for the end-of-line indicator.

findstr on MSDN: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fast native head command that gives you the first 9 lines in DOS.

```
findstr /n "." myfile.txt | findstr "^.:"
```

The first 2 characters on each line will be the line number.

Answer (score 2):

There is a resource kit that can be downloaded from here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/confirmation.aspx?familyId=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd&displayLang=en

It contains a tail.exe tool but it is only compatible with some Windows versions

(Copied from this post: [Tail command for windows](https://www.windows-commandline.com/tail-command-for-windows/))

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried extracting a range, but I was able to get a line using the following DOS command:

```
find /N " " *.log|find "[6]"
```

Since most files contain spaces, this command pulls every line from all LOG files and basically numbers them starting from 1 for each file. The numbered results are then piped into the second `FIND` command which looks for the line tagged as number 6.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, for those just needing to snip off an indeterminate number of records from the head of the file, ***more  >***  works well. This is useful just to have a smaller file to work with in the early stages of developing something.

Answer (score 0):

There's a free `head` utility on [this page](http://www.textpad.com/add-ons/index.html) that you can use. I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: This executes *exactly* like the UNIX head utility.

Answer (score 0):

```
set /p line= < file.csv 
echo %line%
```

it will return first line of your file in cmd Windows in variable %line%.

Answer (score 0):

As a contemporary answer, if running Windows 10 you can use the "Linux Subsystem for Windows".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10

This will allow you to run native linux commands from within windows and thus run tail exactly how you would in linux.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the 1st few lines of text (head):

```
set n=<lines>
for /l %a in (1,1,%n%) do (
for /f "tokens=*" %i in ('find /v /n "" ^< test1.txt ^| find "[%a]"') do (
REM ove prefixed line numbers:
set a=%i
set a=!a:*]=! 
echo:!a!)
)
```

To discard the 1st few lines of text (tail):

```
set n=<lines>
set file=<file.txt>
set /a n=n+1 >nul
for /f "tokens=*" %i in ('find /v /c "" ^< %file%') do set total=%i
for /l %a in (%n%,1,%total%) do (
for /f "tokens=*" %i in ('find /v /n "" ^< %file% ^| find "[%a]"') do (
REM ove prefixed line numbers:
set a=%i
set a=!a:*]=! 
echo:!a!)
)
```

*Note:*
The head function can also be achieved by `fsutil`
The tail function can also be achieved by `fc` & `comp`

Tested on Win 10 cmd

Answer (score -3):

Warning, using the batch file for, tokens, and delims capability on unknown text input can be a disaster due to the special interpretation of chars like &, !, <, etc. Such methods should be reserved for only predictable text.