# Opening a very large file in emacs

Tags: emacs, text-editor, large-data

I am trying open a very large file in Emacs and it fails to load. Is there a way to open only a portion of this very large file? I don't need to open the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use head command, store its output in file and read that file
http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?head

Windows equivalent is here:
[Windows equivalent of the 'tail' command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295068/windows-equiv-of-the-head-command)

Answer (score 3):

You may want to try `vlf.el` which basically runs `head` for you.  It's still pretty crude, sadly.

Answer (score -4):

If all you want is to read parts of a monster file then use this tool http://www.readfileonline.com/. It rapidly cracked open anything I fed it with.