# Printing a sample from a huge file

Tags: bash, powershell

I have a rather large text corpus, of which I would like to check a few lines to see if the format is correct (and to just generally get some idea of its contents). Is there a simple one-liner that can be used to print just the first few lines of a huge text file?

Personally I'm using PowerShell, but answers are appreciated for bash and several other shells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In powershell

```
get-content c:\filename.txt -TotalCount 3 #here just the first 3 line.
```

Comment: I believe that if the file is big it will take time to produce results this way [`as question says its a large text corpus`]?

Comment: @AngshumanAgarwal Tested with a 100MB file not seem to be slow. Don't know with a 1GB file.

Answer (score 1):

The n first lines

```
head -n filename
```

The n first bytes

```
dd if=filename bs=1 count=n
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ head yourfile.txt
```

I'm certain there's an equivalent in PowerShell. I mean, there must be, right?

**Edit:** Yep. [Windows equivalent of the 'tail' command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295068/windows-equiv-of-the-head-command)

Comment: I believe `head` is actually a part of unxutils, so it works here. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`less`](http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/). It's very efficient with large files. And, if you need to see more* you can continue paging through the file.

<sub>*"less is more"</sub>