# What is the Windows/DOS equivalent of the *nix head and tail commands?

Tags: windows, windows-7, dos, command-prompt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for a windows equivalent of the unix tail command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187587/looking-for-a-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-tail-command)
>   [Windows equivalent of the 'tail' command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1295068)

I need to store the first and last 100 lines of a ginormous (multi-gigabyte) XML file. On *nix, I would simply do this:

```
head -n 100 foo.xml > foo.txt
tail -n 100 foo.xml >> foo.txt
```

How can I do the same from a Windows/DOS command prompt?

NOTE: I would prefer not to have to install anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/187587

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1295068

Comment: @RobertHarvey is there any way to get `tail` without installing anything?

Comment: I doubt it.  `head` and `tail` appear to be filters (like DOS's `more` filter), not DOS commands.

Comment: @RobertHarvey not necessarily the `tail` command, just that functionality.

Comment: I'm saying you would have to write a filter, since the equivalent DOS command is not available natively.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to install [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), it comes with all the basic Unix command line tools like `head` and `tail`.