# How to print first 5 lines of the file in windows cmd

Tags: windows, grep, head, windows-console

How can I print first 5 lines of the file in windows CMD?

There is a problem that I can't use PowerShell (spicific task) and batch scripts. Can you help me with this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295068/windows-equiv-of-the-head-command

Comment: more +2 myfile.txt
will print everything after the first two lines. - Doesn't work for me.

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155932/how-do-you-loop-through-each-line-in-a-text-file-using-a-windows-batch-file

Comment: I can't use scripts. I just need to print 5 first lines of the file. That's it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use the more command in some regard.

Maybe 
"more filename P 5"

see
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/227449

Comment: Doesn't work. It prints all lines in file and I need to stop the 'more' process after(this is not allowed). But thanks for your reply

Comment: findstr /n "." myfile.txt | findstr "^.:" gives the first 9 lines

Comment: Okay, that worked. Can you please explain me, what does it mean?

Comment: But, what if I have log file with size 10 GB? It will take a huge amount of time...

Comment: the /n after the first findstr prints out the line numbers so using only that first part would print out the entire file with line numbers. The second findstr limits the lines printed to single digit numbers (since the line number is printed out every line takes the form ".:" with it's first two characters). It's a bit hacky but I dunno how else you would go about doing this

Comment: I tried it on the logfile 2 GB. And it took about of 2 mins. It is very greedy, so I can't use this. But many thanks for your reply

Comment: Yeahhh unfortunately it parses through the entire file

Comment: How come this has been marked as the answer? The given solution prints all lines

Answer (score 5):

Alright, it might be like replying to a very old thread, but still for anyone who would benefit from this.
Use ***findstr***

```
findstr /n . yourfile.txt  | findstr "^[0-5]:"
```

The breakdown is-
first ***findstr*** prints the line number where it finds any character (denoted by a literal dot), second findstr will print lines that start ( using ***^*** for this ) with any number ranging from 0 through 5. Also include ***":"*** there to avoid findstr matching with recurring digits like ***12,13,14... 21,22,23..., etc.*** 
***^[0-5]:*** will match only for lines starting with-

> 1:
> 2:
> 3:
> 4:
> 5:

I tested it on a 250 MB file and it worked within a second.

The same can be achieved in linux using sed-

```
sed -n '1,5p' yourfile.txt
```