# How to skip first several lines when importing CSV from Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, csv, import, skip

I was trying to import a CSV file to my Postgresql with the frist 8 lines skipped and start from the 9th line. My codes below works to read from the second line and treat the first line as header:

```
    create table report(
            id integer,
            name character(3),
            orders integer,
            shipments float

            );

COPY report 
FROM 'C:\Users\sample.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Now how to improve this code to read from the 9th line.
Thank you!

[CSV details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ESWx8.png)

Answer (score 2):

With PostgreSQL 9.3 or newer, `COPY` can refer to a program to preprocess the data, for instance Unix [`tail`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_%28Unix%29).

To start an import at line 9:

```
COPY report  FROM PROGRAM 'tail -n +9 /path/to/file.csv' delimiter ',' csv;
```

Apparently you're using Windows, so `tail` might not be immediately available. Personally I would install it from [`MSYS`](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/msys), otherwise there are alternatives mentioned in
[Looking for a windows equivalent of the unix tail command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187587/)
or [Windows equivalent of the 'tail' command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295068).

Comment: No need for a msys or similar things. The command line programs can be downloaded as native windows binaries: http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/ or http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/