# Powershell break the wait on any key press

Tags: powershell

I have the following command

```
Get-Content -Path out.log -Wait
```

which reads a file and waits.

I want to break the wait on any key press (or a specific key, doesn't matter).

Is it possible?

**UPDATE**

Ctrl + C is not an option because I cannot get rid of "Terminate batch job (Y/N)?" message.

Comment: Ctrl + C is a pretty universal way to break out of a running command.

Comment: @DougMaurer The problem with Ctrl + C is that I cannot get rid of "Terminate batch job (Y/N)?" message

Comment: That’s for a batch script, which is not what you show you’re running.

Comment: Why use the `-Wait` switch? CVan you not just `Pause` after the Get-Content.

Comment: @Scepticalist Because the file out.log is modified by another application after the Get-Content is issued

Answer (score 1):

The closest you can get is to spawn another PowerShell process and to kill that when you press a key. Or the user can simply close the new shell when done.

```
# Start Get-Content -Wait
# Get the Process ID. 
$command = 'get-content -path "C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\Vim\temp.txt" -Wait'

$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command)
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
$psProcess = Start-Process -FilePath pwsh -ArgumentList "-EncodedCommand",$encodedCommand -PassThru

# Wait for input. 
Write-Host "Press any key to to kill Get-Process -Wait."
$host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown") | Out-Null 

# Kill process.
$psProcess.Kill()
```

Failing that, there might be some other way to solve your problem.

What caused you to ask this question? Or what is the background for this problem?

You are only showing the `Get-Content -Wait` cmdlet. That alone does not generate *Terminate batch job*. What other code is running?

There are other *tail* or *watch* tools available. This [search](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffsb&q=watch+tail+programs+&atb=v244-1&ia=web) might be helpful. Or this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295068/windows-equivalent-of-the-tail-command). If you want access to Unix tools, it is possible to [emulate them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Unix%E2%80%93Windows_interoperability) on Windows.